# Passing multiple lines in a text file to a single file

Tags: bash

Please can someone guide on how to achieve the below?
thanks

```
#!/bin/bash
filename='schemas.txt'
while read line; do
echo "-n $line"
done < $filename
```

that spits out

```
-n jon
-n match
```

and i want it as. How do i achieve this?

```
-n jon -n match
```

Comment: Please add content of `schemas.txt` to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in bash using `sed | tr`:

```bash
# prefix -n before each line from input file and 
# converts line break to space
out="$(sed 's/^/-n /' schemas.txt | tr '\n' ' ')"
echo "${out% }" # removes trailing space

-n jon -n match
```

Comment: i am getting result within single quotes? how do i exclude that? ```++ sed 's/^/-n /' schemas.txt
++ tr '\n' ' '
+ name='-n joshg  -n address_match '
+ echo '-n jon  -n match'```

Comment: Values are not in single quotes. That is output of `set -x` (debug). Output of `echo` command won't have any quotes.